# Kill the "homework" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was surprised to see that we have a [homework](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag.  There are currently 9 questions with this tag.

Should we keep this tag or kill it?

Comment: I would follow whatever practice SO has adopted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to being a meta tag (it's not about the content of the question but rather its context), it seems like an attractive nuisance.  We got a [homework question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/9410/1993) from a new user today, who figured out that we have this tag and probably thought that meant he could ask.

I propose that we kill it.

None of the open questions currently on this tag would suffer from the tag's removal.

Comment: KILL IT WITH EXTREME PREJUDICE!!!

Comment: I have to say the tag is still there. I can remove it manually, but I hoped you guys can throw it into the Cracks of Doom.

Comment: @JohnSmithers, thanks for the reminder.  It's gone now.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow has reached the same conclusion: [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

I'm all for duplicating their burnination.

Comment: _I'm Tim Post, and I support this message._

Comment: @Tim, care to do the honors with fire, or should I just detag the questions?

Comment: detag != blacklist.

Comment: @Standback I realize.  I was asking about burnination vs detag.  Sorry that my "with fire" was too subtle. :-)